# Ajax remove from cart woocommerce

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Have a button that adds an item to the cart via ajax on the first click and removes the item from the cart on the second click via ajax. The adding part is easy because `woocommerce` has this built in by default.

I've been told this can be done by:

1. custom jquery code to change a classname for example so you can target the second click
2. A new ajax endpoint to handle reducing cart item stock since WC doesn't have this built in.

I can do the first part fairly easily, but the second part is a bit beyond my scope.

Can anyone help me with this and explain what the code does so I can get a better understanding?